# Warning when putting next() inside promise in navigation guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vue-router

I have a route with a beforeEnter navigation guard. In the guard method there's a promise, and when it resolves it runs `next()`. This makes Vue give me the following warning:

```
missing param for named route "Something": Expected "paramX" to be defined
warn @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:16
```

Now, the thing works as expected, and in the next page `paramX` is available with the intended value. So there doesn't seem to actually be anything wrong, I'd just like to get rid of the warning.

To make it clear:

```
function beforeEnterHook(to, from, next) {
    somePromise.then(() => {
        next()
    })
}

export default new Router({
    ...,
    routes: [
        ...,
        {
            path: '/something/:paramX',
            name: 'Something',
            component: SomeComponent,
            props: true,
            beforeEnter: beforeEnterHook
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: It's unlikely Vue would be issuing that warning for no reason. It's not clear from the code you've provided why that would be occurring. How do you know that the `next()` call is the cause?

Comment: If I put `next()` outside the promise so that it navigates before the promise is resolved there's no warning. But then the data returned by the promise (it's an API call) is not yet available when the next page loads, and I'd like it to be.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The code you have provided will not result in that warning. I cannot help you unless I can reproduce it. [It works for me with no warning.](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/390/)

Comment: As @DecadeMoon, it is highly improbable. Is your somePromise doing some routing side effect?

Comment: It's strange, but I 'm not able to reproduce it either. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hokLcywa/32/) is more or less identical to my code (except names, and component is in its own file), but it throws no warning. I realize it's hard to help when you can't reproduce the warning, and especially when I can't even do it myself. Maybe I could've with more time, but I have to go now... Thanks anyway!